# Display CDATA as text in html

Tags: html

How can I display `<!CDATA[` as text in an html document? I tried wrapping it in `<pre>` tags but that didn't work.

```
<! DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<body>
    <div>This should show <pre><!CDATA[</pre> when the page renders</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should escape the `<` character : "&lt;!CDATA[".

Comment: I realized that right after I posted the question. Sometimes the simple things escape me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers do not support CDATA markers in `text/html` documents. Use character references instead (`&lt;`, `&amp;`, etc).

Comment: The remark is correct, but the question was not really about *using* CDATA but about presenting the string `<!CDATA[`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have written, you should escape “<” as `&lt;`. HTML markup like `pre` or `code` does *not* change the way content is parsed, with “<” as markup-significant. You can use e.g. `code` markup here, since the content is computer code and this markup may have some advantages, but that’s a different issue. Example: `<code>&lt;!CDATA[</code>`.

There is a half-secret markup, however: `<xmp><!CDATA[</xmp>`. Within an `xmp` element, everything is taken literally; only the end tag of this element is recognized. Such markup is regarded as very obsolete by many, and it has been dropped from HTML specs, but it actually keeps working.